# Overview of Active Comments in VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops

In VSTS I can add comments in the browser to a line in any commit (not in a review). [image: Add Comment]

These commits had a status (Active, Resolved, Won't fix and Closed).

[image: Comment Status]

Is there any Overview to see all Active comments or all commits with Active Comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t the way to get all Active comments directly, but you can refer to these steps to build an extension or application with VSTS API to get all Active comments.

1. Get team project’ ID through [Team Projects REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects).
2. Get Repository’ ID through [Git Repositories REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/repositories)
3. Get Commits’ IDs through [Git Commits REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits)
4. Get all comments of a commit with this API:

Request method: Get

```
https://[account].visualstudio.com/_apis/discussion/threads?api-version=3.1-preview.1&artifactUri=vstfs%3A%2F%2F%2FGit%2FCommit%2F[team project id]%252F[repository id]%252F[commit id]
```

5. Get all Active comments per to status of each comment in response result(step 4)

Regarding VSTS extension, you can refer to this article: [Create your first extension for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter comments in the Files tab:

[image]

Comment: I found this only on a commit base. I search the commits, that have active comments.